# Update bar chart in d3 based on user input

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to update the bar chart in d3 based on the input selected by the user. The updated data is being displayed but it is being displayed on the old SVG elements. I tried using exit().remove() but it did not work.
Can anyone edit the code attached below so that the old SVG elements are removed.

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<style>
.rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.text {
  fill: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<select id = "variable">
                    <option >select</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                    <option value="NV">NV</option>          
</select>
<script>
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
        width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0,5])
        .range([height, 0]);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
                .ticks(10);
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var bar;

function update(state)
{
d3.csv("test3.csv", function(error, data) 
    {
            data = data.filter(function(d, i) 
                                { 
                                    if (d['b_state'] == state) 
                                    {
                                    return d;
                                    }
                                });
            data = data.filter(function(d, i) 
                                { 
                                    if (i<10) 
                                    {
                                    return d;
                                    }
                                });

            var barWidth = width / data.length;

            svg.append("g")
                 .attr("class", "y axis")
                 .call(yAxis)
                 .append("text")
                 .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                 .attr("y", 6)
                 .attr("dy", ".71em")
                 .style("text-anchor", "end")
                 .text("Stars");

                bar = svg.selectAll("bar")
                          .data(data)
                          .enter()
                          .append("g")
                          .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)"; });


                bar.append("rect")
                   .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.b_stars); })
                   .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.b_stars); })
                   .attr("width", barWidth - 1)
                   .attr("fill", "steelblue");

                bar.append("text")
                      .attr("x", function(d) { return height - y(d.b_stars); })
                      .attr("y", -40)
                      .attr("dy", ".75em")
                      .text(function(d) { return d.b_name; })
                      .attr("transform", "rotate(90)" );
});
svg.exit().remove();
bar.exit().remove();
}
d3.select("#variable")// selects the variable
  .on("change", function() {// function that is called on changing
    var variableName = document.getElementById("variable").value;// reads the variable value selected into another variable
    update(variableName);});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is about your `bar` selection. You can have a look to this part of the d3 documentation: [Joining data](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data).

By writing

```
bar = svg.selectAll("bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
```

You are selecting all `bar` elements, joining them `data`, and with this `enter()`, you are getting all the `data` items not linked to a `bar` element ([enter() documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_enter)).
But, your `bar` selector matches nothing. The parameter of the `select()`/`selectAll()` has to be a selector (element, class with `.`, id with `#`...). That is why the `enter()` your enter() selection is creating always new elements above the old ones instead of updating them.

So the first step is to rewrite this selection and creating the DOM elements that will match later this selection:

```
bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)"; });
```

Here, we are selecting all elements with the `bar` class. If there is no DOM element linked to an item from `data`, so we are creating it (in the enter() selection), as a new `g` with the `bar` class.

With the selection written like this, on the next call of your update, the `selectAll('.bar')` will match all the `g` previously created and not apply the `enter()` selection for existing elements.

To update or remove your existing bars, you can write your code like this:

```
var barData = svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)

// Bars creation
var barEnter = barData.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)"; });

barEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.b_stars); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.b_stars); })
    .attr("width", barWidth - 1)
    .attr("fill", "steelblue");

barEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return height - y(d.b_stars); })
    .attr("y", -40)
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.b_name; })
    .attr("transform", "rotate(90)" );


// Update the bar if the item in data is modified and already linked to a .bar element
barData.select('rect')
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.b_stars); })

// Remove the DOM elements linked to data items which are not anymore in the data array
barData.exit().remove()
```